# Service Workers using cached files even after updated

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I'm using Angular 14.2.10. We have a service worker that does the following check: whenever the application is in production, this service worker is enabled to check if a new version of the application is available, and then reloads the page with:

```
window.reload()
```

But, there are some machines that are sometimes getting some old version, even if they already installed the new version. For some reason, old files are being rendered for the user, but when they press F5, the system updates again to the new version.

Has anyone experienced this using Angular? Do you have any idea how I can debug this problem, or find what the problem is?